# Почему запросы Sql работают, но на экран выводят ошибки

Tags: sql

Написал два запроса, работают, выполняют свои функции 100 %, но на экран выводят три предупреждения.

Первое предупреждение

> mysqli_fetch_array() ожидает, что параметр 1 будет mysqli_result, null
> задан

Второе предупреждение

> mysqli_num_rows() ожидает, что параметр 1 будет mysqli_result,
> логическое значение задано

Третье предупреждение

> mysqli_free_result() ожидает, что параметр 1 будет mysqli_result,
> логическое значение задано

Писал по Мануалу.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM plateg WHERE id_akk='".$id_user."' ORDER BY data";
$rb = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$rb = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE akk SET summa='".$s."' WHERE id_akk='".$id_user."'")) {
    mysqli_num_rows($result);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так я понял.

Comment: *Писал по Мануалу.* Изменяя имя переменной - изменяй его во всех строках.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.